# Why does rustc take over a minute to compile this 250 line program with optimization while clang takes under a second?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

Background: I made a silly code generation program for various programming languages, the goal being to compare how long it takes various compilers to compile absurdly long 100K+ LOC programs made of simple functions. But when compiling, the Rust version of a program never finished compiling when optimization flags were given to `rustc`.

I discovered that is it easy to make a pretty small Rust program (example below) that takes (to my sensibilities) far too long to compile with the `-C opt-level=2` or `-C opt-level=3` flags for `rustc`. I tried in 1.16 stable, 1.30 stable, 1.32.0-nightly on Linux and 1.30 stable on macOS and Windows - all take what looks to me far too long to compile. I say this because in comparison, roughly equivalent C++ takes under a second to compile with `clang++ -O3`. This leads me to a couple questions:

- Is there an optimization `rustc` is doing (slowly) to this code that `clang` isn't?
- If I wanted to look into this myself, are there good resources to profile `rustc`? It would be cool to see if a particular optimisation in `opt-level=2`  is the culprit.

The [rustc guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/compiler-debugging.html) tells how to turn on debug logs. Using that gets:

```
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(std::rt::lang_start::<()>)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::<(), i8, extern "rust-call" fn(()) -> i32, fn()>)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(std::sys::unix::process::process_common::ExitCode::as_i32)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(<[closure@DefId(1/1:1916 ~ std[424f]::rt[0]::lang_start[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:fn()] as std::ops::FnOnce<()>>::call_once - shim)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(<[closure@DefId(1/1:1916 ~ std[424f]::rt[0]::lang_start[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:fn()] as std::ops::FnOnce<()>>::call_once - shim(vtable))
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(std::ptr::real_drop_in_place::<[closure@DefId(1/1:1916 ~ std[424f]::rt[0]::lang_start[0]::{{closure}}[0]) 0:fn()]> - shim(None))
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(<() as std::process::Termination>::report)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(<std::process::ExitCode as std::process::Termination>::report)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:37:54Z: rustc_codegen_ssa::base: codegen_instance(std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new::<i32>)
INFO 2018-12-09T19:39:12Z: rustc_codegen_llvm::back::lto: 5 symbols to preserve in this crate
INFO 2018-12-09T19:39:12Z: rustc_codegen_llvm::back::lto: going for that thin, thin LTO
```

Notice the minute gap between the last `rustc_codegen_ssa::base` and `rustc_codegen_llvm::back::lto` - how should I interpret this?

[Rust gist](https://gist.github.com/ajdust/9cf976ed2935ad428ee5465cbdef7d56) and [C++ gist](https://gist.github.com/ajdust/5e92cab52ffab5ea2a52edbd47aa348a)

```
//$ rustc -C opt-level=2 test_20.rs
//  takes over a minute to compile, rustc 1.32.0-nightly
//  see https://gist.github.com/ajdust/5e92cab52ffab5ea2a52edbd47aa348a
#![allow(unused_parens)]

fn f0(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let x1: i32 = (p - ((((21 | 1) | p) ^ 84) & ((48 ^ (52 | (p & (2 ^ 61)))) - 67)));
    let x2: i32 = x1;
    let mut x3: i32 = 54;
    let x4: i32 = 75;
    let x5: i32 = (77 & 39);
    let x6: i32 = (x2 * x5);
    let x7: i32 = (88 * (8 + x1));
    x3 = (x3 + 60);
    ((((((((32 * p) & x1) ^ x2) - x3) ^ x4) & x5) | x6) | x7)
}

fn f1(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f0(78);
    x1 = (x1 ^ p);
    let mut x2: i32 = f0(x1);
    x2 = (x2 * 3);
    let x3: i32 = f0(x1);
    let x4: i32 = ((21 & (x3 - ((93 * (x3 - (f0(x3) - (x2 - (f0(x1) | 43))))) | (f0(p) - f0(x1))))) * 41);
    ((((((f0(p) | x2) ^ p) & x1) ^ x2) | x3) - x4)
}

fn f2(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f1(50);
    x1 = (x1 * p);
    x1 = (x1 | f0(p));
    let mut x2: i32 = f1(x1);
    x2 = (x2 | f1(x2));
    let mut x3: i32 = (24 * f0(x1));
    x2 = (x2 & f0(p));
    x3 = (x3 ^ x1);
    let x4: i32 = x1;
    (((((x4 ^ p) | x1) * x2) + x3) | x4)
}

fn f3(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f2(75);
    let x2: i32 = x1;
    x1 = (x1 & x2);
    let x3: i32 = f0(p);
    let x4: i32 = ((f1(x3) ^ f1(x2)) + 92);
    x1 = (x1 | (x2 ^ 94));
    x1 = (x1 * x2);
    let x5: i32 = (f0(x1) & (3 ^ (f0(x1) * f2(x4))));
    x1 = (x1 + x2);
    (((((((x1 * x5) * p) - x1) | x2) * x3) - x4) - x5)
}

fn f4(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f3(14);
    x1 = (x1 + f0(p));
    let mut x2: i32 = f1(x1);
    x1 = (x1 - 41);
    x2 = (x2 ^ 61);
    let x3: i32 = f2(p);
    x2 = (x2 ^ p);
    let x4: i32 = x2;
    x1 = (x1 - p);
    x1 = (x1 * x4);
    ((((((88 & 11) & p) - x1) * x2) ^ x3) | x4)
}

fn f5(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f4(50);
    x1 = (x1 ^ 13);
    ((35 + p) | x1)
}

fn f6(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f5(51);
    x1 = (x1 + 27);
    let x2: i32 = (p + (p | f1(x1)));
    x1 = (x1 + f0(x2));
    let x3: i32 = f0(x1);
    let mut x4: i32 = 48;
    x1 = (x1 ^ f0(p));
    x1 = (x1 & 26);
    x4 = (x4 * f1(x4));
    (((((99 - p) * x1) ^ x2) & x3) + x4)
}

fn f7(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f6(71);
    x1 = (x1 & 66);
    x1 = (x1 & p);
    let x2: i32 = 57;
    x1 = (x1 * 26);
    let x3: i32 = (21 & p);
    let x4: i32 = (f0(x1) & (f3(p) * f2(p)));
    let x5: i32 = f6(x3);
    ((((((x5 + p) | x1) + x2) - x3) & x4) * x5)
}

fn f8(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f7(57);
    x1 = (x1 & f5(p));
    x1 = (x1 ^ (x1 & f1(p)));
    let x2: i32 = 25;
    let x3: i32 = f5(x1);
    ((((x1 - p) * x1) & x2) ^ x3)
}

fn f9(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f8(23);
    x1 = (x1 | (((26 | f4(x1)) - f0(p)) | f8(p)));
    let x2: i32 = x1;
    let mut x3: i32 = 58;
    x3 = (x3 - p);
    let x4: i32 = f7(x1);
    let x5: i32 = f7(x2);
    let x6: i32 = (f7(x1) & 79);
    (((((((33 | p) - x1) + x2) + x3) * x4) ^ x5) + x6)
}

fn f10(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f9(75);
    x1 = (x1 | 37);
    (((f8(x1) + f3(x1)) | p) * x1)
}

fn f11(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f10(8);
    x1 = (x1 ^ f6(x1));
    let mut x2: i32 = p;
    x2 = (x2 ^ 84);
    let x3: i32 = (f5(p) ^ f5(p));
    x1 = (x1 * f5(p));
    x1 = (x1 | f1(x2));
    x1 = (x1 * f8(p));
    ((((((f0(x3) | f9(p)) - f4(x1)) + p) & x1) & x2) - x3)
}

fn f12(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f11(33);
    x1 = (x1 * 84);
    let mut x2: i32 = (67 - f0(p));
    x2 = (x2 | x1);
    x1 = (x1 - 67);
    x2 = (x2 - f6(p));
    (((p - p) * x1) | x2)
}

fn f13(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f12(90);
    x1 = (x1 + (f6(x1) - f4(p)));
    x1 = (x1 - 19);
    let x2: i32 = 92;
    let mut x3: i32 = f9(x1);
    let mut x4: i32 = x3;
    x4 = (x4 - (87 | f5(x3)));
    x3 = (x3 | 49);
    let x5: i32 = 25;
    let x6: i32 = x3;
    (((((((2 & p) - x1) ^ x2) ^ x3) ^ x4) | x5) | x6)
}

fn f14(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f13(66);
    let x2: i32 = f2(p);
    x1 = (x1 - 11);
    let mut x3: i32 = 69;
    x3 = (x3 * x2);
    let x4: i32 = 91;
    (((((19 * p) + x1) | x2) ^ x3) & x4)
}

fn f15(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f14(79);
    x1 = (x1 + (f8(p) & p));
    let x2: i32 = p;
    x1 = (x1 | ((f5(p) & x2) ^ x2));
    let mut x3: i32 = x1;
    x1 = (x1 - p);
    x3 = (x3 * p);
    ((((40 * p) ^ x1) + x2) + x3)
}

fn f16(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let x1: i32 = f15(77);
    let mut x2: i32 = 5;
    let mut x3: i32 = x1;
    let x4: i32 = p;
    x2 = (x2 + p);
    let x5: i32 = x4;
    x3 = (x3 | f9(x4));
    let x6: i32 = (68 ^ (61 ^ (24 * f14(x4))));
    (((((((88 + p) - x1) & x2) | x3) & x4) ^ x5) | x6)
}

fn f17(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f16(41);
    x1 = (x1 | 4);
    let mut x2: i32 = x1;
    x1 = (x1 | 52);
    x1 = (x1 & 49);
    x2 = (x2 & (f8(x2) ^ p));
    let mut x3: i32 = x2;
    x3 = (x3 ^ ((x1 ^ x2) + f15(x2)));
    let mut x4: i32 = (f13(x2) ^ 73);
    x4 = (x4 - f12(x1));
    (((((x3 - p) + x1) ^ x2) + x3) | x4)
}

fn f18(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut x1: i32 = f17(3);
    x1 = (x1 & (p - ((33 * (95 | 87)) | (9 - f1(x1)))));
    x1 = (x1 & (80 - f16(x1)));
    x1 = (x1 & p);
    x1 = (x1 + p);
    x1 = (x1 | (82 - ((81 ^ p) - 97)));
    ((20 - p) * x1)
}

fn f19(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let x1: i32 = f18(24);
    let x2: i32 = (p & p);
    let mut x3: i32 = 82;
    let x4: i32 = (4 + x1);
    x3 = (x3 | ((f10(p) + (f16(x3) - 34)) - f10(x1)));
    let x5: i32 = (x4 | (x1 * (((f16(x1) + f4(x4)) - 43) & f7(x3))));
    (((((((f14(x3) | f9(x5)) - p) & x1) * x2) & x3) * x4) + x5)
}

fn f20(p: i32) -> i32 {
    let x1: i32 = f19(78);
    let x2: i32 = 81;
    let x3: i32 = (x2 + (59 & x1));
    (((((f9(x3) ^ f11(x3)) * p) * x1) - x2) ^ x3)
}

fn main() {
    let mut x0: i32 = f20(65);
    x0 = (x0 * (53 + 37));
    let mut x1: i32 = (x0 - ((41 | ((f20(x0) * f9(x0)) + ((((f20(x0) + (77 + (f14(x0) ^ 60))) * 27) & 62) + x0))) & f20(x0)));
    let x2: i32 = f15(x1);
    x1 = (x1 | (x0 * (4 ^ 37)));
    let m: i32 = (((x2 | x0) | x1) | x2);
    println!("{}", m);

}
```

Comment: Just for diagnosis, some notes, `-Ztime-passes` shows it is in a llvm module pass and compiling with `-Cinline-threshold=1000` makes it compile in an instant again. (We can't blame llvm — rustc is responsible for what it is giving it as input.)  This should be a bug report to rust-lang/rust

Comment: LTO is pretty hyper-liberal about inlining. Given it says "5 symbols to preserve", I suspect those 5 are `f20`, `f9`, `f14`, `f15` (the four called in `main`), and `main` itself. I suspect it's doing some sort of full inline followed by a full reachability analysis and cull of unused code and trying to create a program as small and inlined as possible which is slow but usually what you *want* if you turn on LTO. Not certain if something better can be passed to LLVM to speed some of this up, though.

Comment: I don't know if O3 in C++ turns on similar behavior by default, it's possible whatever C++'s equivalent optimization is is behind a different flag and would produce similarly long results? I wonder if this is closer to some weird union of -O3 -Oz.

Comment: Thanks @bluss & @LinearZoetrope. That flag `-Cinline-threshold` is what I was looking for. Considering that the same binary is created compiling both with and without it, it's interesting that it isn't the default behavior.

Comment: @bluss I should look around the rustlang/rust issues to see if there's anything similar to reference, as this might be in a discussion about what defaults goes into the opt-levels, and see about making an issue/bug report. When I get around to that I'll answer/comment this post. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronB: Just because a particular setting has no effect on one particular binary does not lead to the conclusion that the setting is ineffective by default. You've uncovered an edge case, it needs to be analyzed and understood before any "corrective" action is taken :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was effectively answered in the comments - thanks @bluss. Passing the `-Cinline-threshold=1000` to `rustc` brings the compilation speed down to the expected speed of under a second or so.

As this can still be replicated 2.5 years later, I finally followed through with the suggestion to create a bug report issue in the rust-lang repo to see if there's a way Rust can be improved. You can see that bug report issue here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86870

Thanks to all who commented.